# Google Sheets SUMIF Using Partial Date/Time Stamp as Wild Card Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I am trying to figure out a SUMIF formula that looks for a partial dat/time match and sums a range based on that match. I am using the date data validation in one cell as the criteria, but the range that I am attempting to match it to is formatted differently, so it isn't working. The dates in the criteria range are formatted as "MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS" and the date in the criteria cell is formatted "MM/DD/YY" because it's selected from the calendar pop up.

- Here is the formula I have, and it works if I edit the criteria range values to "MM/DD/YY", but this isn't a practical option for me, as this value is duplicated on multiple sheets in different number formats.

  =SUMIFS(Data!G:G,Data!F:F,"*"&N8&"*")
- I'm using SUMIFS here instead of SUMIF because I'll be adding multiple criteria once I figure this piece out.
- I'm sorry I can't share this sheet as it's for work, but it's fairly straightforward. I am trying here to use a wildcard for cell N8, which contains the date validation, to find the partial date match from F:F Range, and then SUM matching values in G:G range, but when the format contains the time, it doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have true dates, use formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(Data!G:G,INT(Data!F:F),N8))
```

if dates are entered as text, then:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(Data!G:G,LEFT(Data!F:F,10),N8))
```

in this case months and days must be formatted with leading zero.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below formula:

```
=sumifs(Data!G:G,,arrayformula(value(text(Data!F:F,"mm/dd/yy"))),""&N8&"")
```